# PDO::FETCH_ASSOC not returning values. I am confused between different approaches, can you hel me resolve them?

Tags: php, mysql, list, pdo

I am quite unused with php.
I want to create a menu by taking objects from a database, but i am confused by all the different methods of doing so (both from school and internet) and i need to make some order in my mind.

This is what i have done until now, i use two different classes for doing so.

Db.php

```
class Db extends PDO {

    private $uname;
    private $passwd;
    private $hostname;
    private $dbname;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->uname = "root";
        $this->passwd = "";
        $this->hostname = "127.0.0.1";
        $this->dbname = "myclienti";

        try {
            parent::__construct('mysql:charset=utf8mb4;host=' . $this->hostname . ';dbname=' . $this->dbname, $this->uname, $this->passwd);
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }
    }

}
```

Servizie.php

```
class Servizie {
    private $codice_utente;
    private $desc_servizio;
    private $puntopresa;



    function getCodice_utente() {
        return $this->codice_utente;
    }

    function getDesc_servizio() {
        return $this->desc_servizio;
    }

    function getPuntopresa() {
        return $this->puntopresa;
    }

    function setCodice_utente($codice_utente) {
        $this->codice_utente = $codice_utente;
    }

    function setDesc_servizio($desc_servizio) {
        $this->desc_servizio = $desc_servizio;
    }

    function setPuntopresa($puntopresa) {
        $this->puntopresa = $puntopresa;
    }




    public function getAllServizie() {
        $db = new Db();

        $query = 'select CODICE_UTENTE, DESC_SERVIZIO, PUNTOPRESA from serviziele';
        $statement = $db->prepare($query);
        $statement->execute();
        $object = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        return $object;

    }

}
```

Part of my index page where i want to put my menu.

```
       <?php
        $servizie = new Servizie();


        $list = $servizie->getAllServizie();
        echo '<div id="dropdown-contentelectr">';
        foreach ($list as $element){
            echo '<a href="#">' . $element->PUNTOPRESA . '</a>';
        }

        echo '</div>';
        ?>
```

Sorry for my english.

Comment: Since you fetched an associative array you need to use `$element['PUNTOPRESA']` instead of object notation.

Comment: Or use `PDO::FETCH_OBJ` instead.

Comment: from serviziele my nizzle!

Comment: It works, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When fetching as Associative Array, you retrive data by index

```
$element['PUNTOPRESA'];
```

If you want to fetch as Class/instance, use:

```
PDO::FETCH_INTO
PDO::FETCH_CLASS
```

Or for \stdClass which returns an anonymous object.

```
PDO::FETCH_OBJ
```

These will allow to access properties of the fetched object with arrow notation.

Usage:

```
statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
```

For more, read:
http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php

If you want an example of Database class look at that (it's part of a micro-framework so just take it as example, written by me):
https://github.com/yuxblank/phackp/blob/master/src/phackp/core/Database.php

Comment: There are some critical faults in your class. You may find useful this article I wrote after revising dozents of PHP wrappers, [Your first database wrapper's childhood diseases](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo/common_mistakes)

Comment: Thank you, it's just an alpha release. I will give a read in order to optimize it and produce a stable release. If you would like to edit and post a more complete solution it's ok for me.

Comment: Well if you ask me, a more complete solution would be as simple as just a simple function run() from here: https://phpdelusions.net/pdo/pdo_wrapper#run Everything else will be handled by PDO.

Comment: I don't really like it. First in that way you still make alot of boilerplate code and you create somewhat like Facades (using static methods, singleton way) that i'd not use. Every time you get a statement, that has to be again coded (so boring!) and each class should use PDO to know about Fetch modes etc etc. My way (although still early) provides a clearer/faster way to access pdo (a simplified interface). Maybe you loose some performance (not so much) but the code will be less and more coincise (although less complete)

Comment: You just didn't get that code. Nobody asks you to create a singleton, and nobody asks you co code a statement. In fact without pdo fetch modes you are losing a lot of PDO features, which make you write a lot boilerplate in the end. But it's all right - it always takes time to understand that simpler code is better, so just get your time.